# Multiple version of the web application running on different servers

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, web

How do I separate the web application (built in ASP.NET) and database (built in SQL Server 2005), so that we could have multiple version of the web application running on different servers?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Your plan is to install the SQL Server on one server and the IIS with different version of your web application on 20 others?

Comment: @Mafix:- 
 The question here means we have our source code and database with us. The live code have some latest feature and its running on a server, say server1. We dont have source code and database of the past. Some how we can get the past source code (say abut 2 months back) via SVN and by some how we will have the past database as well. Now how to runn the present web app. as version 2 and past app. as version1 on the same IIS server or varsion1 on different server and version 2 on different. Hope this make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Database**: your best two options here are to:

- generate SQL scripts. This will allow you to run a bunch of `CREATE` statements against as many SQL Server instances as you need. Use the [SQL Server Generate Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365071/migrate-sql-server-express-tables-to-sql-server-database/7365182#7365182) command
- create a backup of your current database. This will give you a .BAK file. For each SQL Server instance you need, here are two article to restore from backup: [Create a New Database From an Existing Backup from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx) and [Restore a SQL Server database to a New Server from TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-new-server/454) onto.

**Web app**: copy the application or deploy with Visual Studio to your targets. The target could be another directory on the server, or another machine entirely. Ensure your connection string points to the correct instance.

Comment: Many thanks it seems like a plan to me, hope it will work, many thanks again